# failed to read subprocess Output line by line

Tags: python, subprocess

I am quite new in 'subprocess' function and wanna to read the output of the command run within python code.

It seems that no problem arose when I line by line ran my code unter python, but when I ran it in bash by typing 'python test.py' (test.py is where my code was packed) it ended up with only `b''` and results from 'head' command however were not showed.

```
import subprocess
pro = subprocess.Popen("sed 's/A/N/g *.txt | head Quelle1.txt'", shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
content = pro.stdout.readlines()
for line in content:
    print(list)
```

any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: After you ran it the first time, the `.txt` content has already been replaced, so on the second run there is nothing more to do would be my guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see empty output because process has been started in a new process but probably haven't finished yet ([subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)). When you do everything line by line - you paste commands slower than they get executed.

For a better way - see a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16266707/3500157)

The idea is to wrap in "with" construction

```
with subprocess.Popen(...) as p:
  pass # your code here
```