# Python subprocess function uname -a returnvalue

Tags: python-2.7, shell, subprocess

I have some questions about the subprocess function in python 2.7 I want to build an script that forms an if clause like:

```
Import os
Import subprocess
process = subprocess ('uname -a')
if process == 'ESXi':
    print ('yey')
```

I am sorry that the code has many mistakes and that my english is so poorly (motherlanguage greek)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to check if the output value contains 'ESXi'

Comment: You want a substring match? https://stackoverflow.com/q/3437059/1531971

Comment: Yes, just compared with the output value of the shell function uname -a

Comment: You should say this in the question body: I want to run a subprocess and get the results from "uname -a" as a string. I then want to test whether or not this result contains the string "ESXi".

Comment: I am very sorry, i am not very good in english

Comment: Also, this code doesn't seem to be valid Python. Remember: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You probably need to use `subprocess.check_output()` and then `in` for testing the result. See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the output of your command

```
word = 'ESXi'
process = subprocess.check_output(['uname','-a'])  
if word in str(process):   
   print ('yey')
```

result of your command will be in process

for more info [(python doc)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) and [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575284/check-output-from-calledprocesserror/8235171#8235171)

also, refer [otheres question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996518/retrieving-the-output-of-subprocess-call)