# Python subprocess run skip prompt

Tags: python, subprocess, prompt

What is the correct way to skip prompt when running a subprocess such as `git push`

```
import subprocess as sp
sp.run(['git', 'push', 'origin', 'HEAD'], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, check=True)
```

I want it to throw a `CalledProcessError` if the remote ask for credentials (as if you type it wrong)

Edit :

> @Rex Low : Possible duplicate of check output from CalledProcessError

even with `check_output` it opens a prompt in the serveur terminal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check output from CalledProcessError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575284/check-output-from-calledprocesserror)

Comment: No, even with `check_output` it opens a prompt