# Get print() realtime output with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to execute a Python file from another Python file and show all `print()` outputs and error outputs without waiting (realtime).

The simplified version of my code is as follows and I would like to show "start" and an error message without waiting for "end" (the end of the script).

```
def main():
    # Function that takes a long time (in my actual code)
    x += 1 # this raises an error

if __name__ == "main":
    print("start")
    main()
    print("end")
```

I also have `run.py`:

```
import subprocess

def run():
    subprocess.run(["python", "main.py"])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I tried [this blog post](https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2015/01/28/getting-realtime-output-using-python) and several other similar answers on stackoverflow, but none of them worked, so I decided to put my original code here, which is above.

Comment: try using check_output() https://stackoverflow.com/a/8235171/546375

Comment: What difficulties did you have implementing the blog post you linked? stdout is buffered so you might want to do `print('start', flush=True)` to force output so the listening process has something to retrieve...

Comment: I do not think subprocess has a `run()` method, it should be `call()`, right?

Comment: @KetanMukadam: [It does in Python 3.5+.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work for me (on Windows). It uses `subprocess.Popen()` to execute the other script because this gives more control over what goes on. It turns `buffering` off to eliminate any delays that might cause, plus it redirects stderr to stdout to so all output can be retrieved from a single source.. Also note it also includes the correction @Ketan Mukadam mentions is [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51918439/355230) tregarding the value of `__name__` in your first script.

**`main_script.py`**:

```
def main():
    # Function that takes a long time (in my actual code)
    x += 1 # this raises an error

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("start")
    main()
    print("end")
```

**`run.py`**:

```
import subprocess
import sys

def run():
    kwargs = dict(bufsize=0,  # No buffering.
                  stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                  stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,  # Redirect stderr to stdout.
                  universal_newlines=True)
    args = [sys.executable, 'main_script.py']

    with subprocess.Popen(args, **kwargs).stdout as output:
        for line in output:
            print(line, end='')  # Process the output...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Output from executing `run.py`:

```
start
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_script.py", line 10, in <module>
    main()
  File "main_script.py", line 6, in main
    x += 1 # this raises an error
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this line a mistake?

```
if __name__ == "main":
```

The symbol is `__main__` set by interpreter and not `main`. It is possible that because of this typo error no code is running from main script. Try first executing the main script directly on command shell.