# Retrieving versions of a file

Tags: python, git, gitpython

Say I have a path to a git repository in the local filesystem: `path_to_my_repository`, and a path to a file in the repository `path_to_file`.

For a given list of dates, how can I get the corresponding version of the file on a particular branch **from Python** (i.e. loading the file in memory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shell command should do what you want:

```
git show "<branch>@{<timestamp>}:<path/to/file>"
```

For example:

```
git show "master@{yesterday}:some/file/in/repo"
git show "master@{2014-01-01 00:00:00}:another/file"
```

This prints to `STDOUT`.

To run this from an arbitrary directory, you can use the `-C` option to point to your repository root:

```
git -C path_to_my_repository show "master@{2014-05-05 12:00:00}:path_to_file"
```

You can run this from Python using [the `subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) [like this, or something close to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996518/retrieving-the-output-of-subprocess-call):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(['git', '-C', path_to_my_repository, 'show',
        'master@{' + date_string + '}:' + path_to_file],
    stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

# Content will be in `output`
output, err = p.communicate()
```

or using any other method to call a shell command. You should also be able to [use libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2), or a number of other tools.

Comment: Thanks, I am unable to replicate this though, even in the shell: `git -C /Users/josh/code/reps/my_repo show "master@{2014-05-01 12:00:00}:/Users/josh/code/reps/my_repo/learning/main/config.xml" fatal: Path '/Users/josh/code/reps/my_repo/learning/main/config.xml' exists on disk, but not in 'master@{2014-05-01 12:00:00}`. However, I definitely know that file existed on that date.

Comment: @user815423426, the path should be a relative path within the repository. For example, in your case I believe you want to use `learning/main/config.xml`.