# How to check if subprocess terminated properly?

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to know if the `subprocess.call()` has terminated correctly without any error in the called function. For example, in the below code, if the path provided is not appropriate, the `ls` command gives an error as:

> ERROR:No such file or directory.

I want same output to be stored as string.

```
import subprocess
path = raw_input("Enter the path")
subprocess.call(["ls","-l",path])
```

Comment: a similar question has already been asked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996518/retrieving-the-output-of-subprocess-call

Comment: @GeorgeSimms: In general the output and the exit status are different things. It might be enough to know the return code without retrieving subprocess' stdout/stderr, to check whether the subprocess terminated properly e.g., nonzero exit status often indicates an error (it depends on the subprocess) regardless of stdout/stderr value.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian the author asks
- for whether the subprocess succeeded (which can be determined from the falsiness of the exit code)
- the output of the subprocess to stdout/stderr as a string (which can be obtained by calling `communicate` on the result of Popen)

`subprocess.call` is insufficient because the output to stdout/stderr cannot be retrieved. Otherwise we could do `something_went_wrong() if subprocess.call(stuff) else we_are_ok()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(["ls", "-l", path], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate()
status = p.returncode
if  status:
  # something went wrong
  pass
else:
  # we are ok
  pass
```

Although consider using `os.listdir`

Comment: You don't need to read the output, to check the success status. to get the exit status; it is enough to store `subprocess.call()` return value (an integer). Nonzero status means an error in many cases. The output could be redirected to DEVNULL, to avoid noise e.g., `stderr=DEVNULL`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian OP explicitly stated that wants to read the output.

Comment: @BartoszKP: I know. The comment is for people who landed on the page due to its title.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Consider fixing the title instead :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with [`call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call), because what it does is only:

> Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return the returncode attribute.

So you can only determine the return code of a program, which usually means zero if no error occurred, and non-zero otherwise.

Use the [`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) method from the same module:

```
try:
    result = subprocess.check_output(["ls", "-l", path],
                                     stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
    print result
except subprocess.CalledProcessError, e:
    print "Error:", e.output
```

Here is a [working demo](http://ideone.com/kYPLqz).

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. The approach clearly works and uses a method that is documented for this purpose.

Comment: probably because check_output is not the as using call, you would use  check_call

Comment: @PadraicCunningham You can't use `check_call` here because it won't return the output as string. Similarly to `call` it only returns an error code.

Comment: I missed the storing as a string part.