# How to execute a user input like date as command in python subprocess module

Tags: python, subprocess

If i get the input as ls, how to pass the value in the call function and get output?

Example

$ Enter any command: 
  ls

$ log.txt file.txt

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996518/retrieving-the-output-of-subprocess-call

Comment: By get output you mean print it (as in the example) or returning value?

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying [Retrieving the output of subprocess.call()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996518/retrieving-the-output-of-subprocess-call) for the question:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-l'], stdout = PIPE)
result = p.communicate()
```

Comment: use `subprocess.check_output()` as shown in the 2nd answer of the question that you've linked.