# What difference between subprocess.call() and subprocess.Popen() makes PIPE less secure for the former?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen, python-2.6

I've had a look at the documentation for both of them.

This question is prompted by J.F.'s comment here: [Retrieving the output of subprocess.call()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996518/retrieving-the-output-of-subprocess-call#comment31660313_1996540)

The current Python documentation for [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) says the following about using `PIPE` for `subprocess.call()`:

> Note Do not use `stdout=PIPE` or `stderr=PIPE` with this function. The child process will block if it generates enough output to a pipe to fill up the OS pipe buffer as the pipes are not being read from.

Python 2.7 [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

> Note Do not use `stdout=PIPE` or `stderr=PIPE` with this function as that can deadlock based on the child process output volume. Use Popen with the communicate() method when you need pipes.

Python 2.6 includes no such warnings.

Also, the [`subprocess.call()` and `subprocess.check_call()`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/subprocess.html#convenience-functions) don't seem to have a way to access their output, except for using stdout=PIPE with communicate():

https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/subprocess.html#convenience-functions

> Note that if you want to send data to the process’s `stdin`, you need to create the `Popen` object with `stdin=PIPE`. Similarly, to get anything other than None in the result tuple, you need to give `stdout=PIPE` and/or `stderr=PIPE` too.

https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

What difference between `subprocess.call()` and `subprocess.Popen()` makes `PIPE` less secure for `subprocess.call()`?

**More Specific:** Why does `subprocess.call()` *"deadlock based on the child process output volume."*, and not `Popen()`?

Comment: // , Followup question: How does this difference change between Python 2 and Python 3?

Comment: Why do you keep starting everything with `//`?

Comment: @chepner: Well, the button does say "Add Comment"....  :)

Comment: // , Follow-up Question for Meta: Why do so few people have a sense of humor on SO?

Comment: # @NathanBasanese Perhaps I'm [completely missing the point](https://allthetropes.orain.org/wiki/Comically_Missing_the_Point), but the Python comment symbol is `#`, unlike in C++, PHP, and JavaScript.

Comment: // , Well, I guess this page runs JavaScript?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`call()` is just `Popen().wait()` (± error handling)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b01cfb8f69e0990be0615b8613a7412f88bd217a/Lib/subprocess.py#L552-L566).

**You should not use `stdout=PIPE` with `call()`** because it does not read from the pipe and therefore the child process will hang as soon as it fills the corresponding OS pipe buffer. Here's a picture that shows how data flows in `command1 | command2` shell pipeline:

[image: pipe/stdio buffers]

It does not matter what your Python version is -- the pipe buffer (look at the picture) is outside of your Python process. Python 3 does not use C stdio but it affects only the internal buffering. When the internal buffer is flushed the data goes into the pipe. If `command2` (your parent Python program) does not read from the pipe then `command1` (the child process e.g., started by `call()`) will hang as soon as the pipe buffer is full ([`pipe_size = fcntl(p.stdout, F_GETPIPE_SZ)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) ~65K on my Linux box (max value is `/proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size` ~1M)).

**You may use `stdout=PIPE` if you read from the pipe** later e.g., using `Popen.communicate()` method. You could also [read from `process.stdout` (the file object that represents the pipe) directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279).

Comment: // , It looks like the "pipe" metaphor works quite well. I did not know I could take it so literally that there could be a _stuffed_ pipe. Makes me wonder why the kernel's pipe buffer for that command does not just flush itself automatically, or why `call()` wouldn't just flush that buffer. To extend the "pipe" metaphor, if the pipe is installed somewhere that might not get out of the pipe, why not leave a pressure-activated connection (solenoid valve?) to the drainage sump? ("Flush that Buffer! Make code Tougher!"-Possible Slogan?)

Comment: // , I can guess why some call systems programmers "Plumbers." It's all in the pipes.

Comment: There is a way to say "flush the pipe buffer automatically";  it is called: "drop data" implemented as `stdout=DEVNULL` (you can use it safely with `call()`).

Comment: // , Ah, but then one no longer has the option of, later, possibly using `communicate()` with the output of `call()` or the output of `check_call()`, right?

Comment: @NathanBasanese: `call()` returns child's exit status -- it is an ordinary integer (8-bit range on POSIX, 32-bit -- on Windows); you can't call `communicate()` with it. Anyway, the child process is already dead, even its PID may be reused already by other processes by the time `call()` returns. `check_call()` is just `call()` that raises an exception if the exit status is non-zero. It would be a useful exercise to implement a shell pipeline using only POSIX calls: pipe, fork, exec, dup2, waitpid e.g., [`recursive-pipe.c`](https://gist.github.com/zed/7835043)

Answer (score 2):

Both `call` and `Popen` provide means of accessing the output of your command:

- With `Popen` you can use `communicate` or provide a file descriptor or file object to the `stdout=...`  parameter.
- With `call` your only option is to pass a file descriptor or a file object to the `stdout=...`  parameter (you can not use `communicate` with this one).

Now, the reason why `stdout=PIPE` is insecure when used with `call` is because `call` doesn't return until the subprocess has finished, this means all the output would have to reside in memory until that moment, and if the amount of output is too much then that would fill the OS pipes' buffer.

The references where you can validate the above information are the following:

1. According to [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) the parameters for both `call` and `Popen` are the same:

> The arguments shown above are merely the most common ones, described
>   below in Frequently Used Arguments (hence the slightly odd notation in
>   the abbreviated signature). The full function signature is the same as
>   that of the Popen constructor - this functions passes all supplied
>   arguments directly through to that interface.

2. According to [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) the possible values for the `stdout` parameter are:

> Valid values are PIPE, an existing file descriptor (a positive
>   integer), an existing file object, and None. PIPE indicates that a new
>   pipe to the child should be created

Comment: // , Er, does `stdout=POPEN`, in the fourth paragraph, actually mean `stdout=PIPE`, or is `POPEN` a worthy file descriptor?

Comment: // , Like I said, I did read through the documentation. I read it way too many times. It made me sad. Also, as to the bullet • points, I know that you have to pass a file descriptor or file object, and that PIPE is a bad idea, but I am just wondering _why_ that is less secure in the case of `subprocess methods. Also, in the fourth paragraph, why does the first part occur for the convenience functions, and not for Popen()? Why does this difference cause the "this means..." part?

Comment: @NathanBasanese Hi, about the `stdout=POPEN` thing, yes, it was a typo. Now it is corrected. About your other doubts: the reason is that with `Popen() + PIPE` you can call `communicate()` as many times as you want to avoid the internal OS pipe's buffer from filling, while in the case of `call() + PIPE` you cannot invoke `communicate()` as your process blocks as soon as you invoke `call()`.