# Ruby running from Python subprocess giving wrong version

Tags: python, ruby, subprocess

I have a subprocess in Python, which runs a Ruby script.

```
import subprocess
cmd="ruby -v"
p=subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, env={ 'PATH': '/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin' })
p.wait()
output, errors = p.communicate()
status = 'Estado de la app: ' + str(output) + 'Errores: ' + str(errors)
return status
```

The problem is that it gives a wrong Ruby version. This runs on a server so through SSH I installed Ruby 2.2.1 with rvm, and when I run `ruby -v` it gives me the right information. But when I run the python from web2py it gives me an older version of Ruby, which is the one in /usr/bin/ruby.

It is like the subprocess runs in a whole different shell. What could it be?

Thanks

Comment: SSH into the box and run `which ruby`. Try the same from within your script. Try using the full path name to invoke the Ruby interpreter you want to use in the script.

Comment: unrelated: drop `p.wait()` call. It may deadlock your program and it is completely unnecessary here, see [What difference between subprocess.call() and subprocess.Popen() makes PIPE less secure for the former?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32364849/4279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this:

```
/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.2.1/ruby /scripts/myscript.rb
```

Which means I execute the ruby from the folder of rvm.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

`rvm` works by injecting hooks into your shell. This is typically done in your `.bash_profile` (see [here](https://rvm.io/rvm/install)).

Bash is probably your default shell, but regardless, your `.bash_profile` [is only read by your shell *if it's a login shell*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/438150/scripts-in-etc-profile-d-being-ignored), which a shell spawned by `subprocess.Popen` isn't. In other words, `rvm` isn't loaded at all when you use `subprocess.Popen`

To fix your issue, you should explicitly invoke `rvm`:

```
rvm 2.2.1 do ruby ...
```

(e.g. in your case `rvm 2.2.1 do ruby -v`)

This is documented in [the rvm scripting documentation](https://rvm.io/workflow/scripting).

Comment: Tried, but I get "rum not found". I'll post how I solved it.