# Returning mp4 from wsgi app

Tags: uwsgi

I want to return an `mp4` from a wsgi application. I'm not using Django or other framework. The `mp4` is returned by the `parseParams` function:

```
def parseParams(params):
    // cmd invokes ffmpeg, which writes output to pipe:1 (stdout)
    return [ call(cmd) ]

form = "<html>...</html>"

def application(environ, start_response):
    x = handle_post(environ)
    if (isinstance(x, dict)):
        start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','video/mp4')])
        return parseParams(x)
    else:
        start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
        return [form]
```

The logs are full of binary data, presumably the output of `ffmpeg`, and nothing is returned to the browser, although I can see that the mime type header is properly set. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, no sooner do I post a question than I get it to work. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996518/retrieving-the-output-of-subprocess-call) and modified `parseParams` to end this way:

```
 proc = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE)
 out, err = proc.communicate()
 return [ out ]
```

Works perfectly!

Comment: I had to remove the brackets from the `return` statement.  But otherwise, this was just what I needed.