# Is it possible to embed and run Python code on HTML?

Tags: python, html, flask, embed

I'm trying to run a Python script with HTML code embedded and it's not working. I'm want to execute a Python script and at the same time render the HTML which will be printed by the script.

`app.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/briefing')
def briefing():
    return render_template('briefing.html')

@app.route('/briefing/code')
def app_code():
    return render_template('app_code.py')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`app_code.py`:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIFFJ.png

When I access `http://127.0.0.1:5000/briefing/code` the result is https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEKv2.png.

I know that what is happening is that I'm rendering as HTML and therefore the Python code inside of the file is not being interpreted.

How can I run the `app_code.py` and at the same time, render the HTML from it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are mixing up a lot of things, I saw the first post of the question took me a while to figure out what you are trying to do.

The idea that you seem to need to grasp is that, you'll need to prepare the *model* in Python first (e.g. a string, an object, a dict etc with the data you want), and then inject it into a *template* to be rendered (as opposed to printing out what you want to see in the HTML output)

If you want to display the output from a `subprocess.call` into an HTML page, here's what you should do:

- [Get the output from subprocess in a string format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996518/retrieving-the-output-of-subprocess-call)
- Create a HTML template to display it in
- Make Flask call the subprocess, render the template and return the HTTP response

`app.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6
import subprocess
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

def get_data():
    """
    Return a string that is the output from subprocess
    """

    # There is a link above on how to do this, but here's my attempt
    # I think this will work for your Python 2.6

    p = subprocess.Popen(["tree", "/your/path"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()

    return out

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('subprocess.html', subprocess_output=get_data())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`subprocess.html`:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Subprocess result</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Subprocess Result</h1>
{{ subprocess_output }}
</body>
</html>
```

In the above template, `{{ subprocess_output }}` will be replaced by the value you pass from your Flask view before the resulting HTML page is sent to the browser.

### How to pass more than one value

You can either `render_template('page.html', value_1='something 1', value_2='something 2')`

and in the template: `{{ value_1 }}` and `{{ value_2}}`

Or you can pass a dict called e.g. `result`:

`render_template('page.html, result={'value_1': 'something 1', 'value_2': 'something 2'})`

and in the template `{{ result.value_1 }}` and `{{ result.value_2 }}`