# Call functions of an external program from Python

Tags: python, c++, qt, subprocess

I'm trying to access, from Python, some functions of a `subprocess`-spawned external C++ program. The program is a Qt application, whose main header is shown below:

```
#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {

public slots:
    void saveSnapshot();
    void updateImage();

}
```

Allowing minimal modifications to the application's source code, is it possible to call slots `saveSnapshot()` and `updateImage()` (which are otherwise triggered by buttons on the GUI) from my Python program?

Comment: after running `Popen` Python can communicate with external program only using `stdin` and `stdout`. It has no access to function `saveSnapshot()` and `updateImage()`. It can't run them and get their results.

Comment: maybe you could use modules like `PyAutoGui` to click buttons in external program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving the output of subprocess.call()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996518/retrieving-the-output-of-subprocess-call)

Comment: Furas, without using PyAutoGui, is there any workaround to this, so that the functions can be accessed by `stdin` and `stdout`?