# Python: Capture stdout from subprocess.call

Tags: python

I'm trying to do two things when executing a shell cmd with Python:

- Capture stdout and print it *as it happens*
- Capture stdout as a whole and process it when the cmd is complete

I looked at [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output), but it does not have an stdout param that would allow me to print the output as it happens.

So after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996518/retrieving-the-output-of-subprocess-call), I realized I may need to try a different approach.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen(task_cmd, stdout = PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

print(stdout, stderr)
```

The problem with this approach is that according to the docs, [Popen.communicate()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

> Reads data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached.
>   Wait for process to terminate

I still cannot seem to redirect output both to stdout AND to some sort of buffer that can be parsed when the command is complete.

Ideally, I'd like something like:

```
# captures the process output and dumps it to stdout in realtime
stdout_capture = Something(prints_to_stdout = True)
process = Popen(task_cmd, stdout = stdout_capture)

# prints the entire output of the executed process
print(stdout_capture.complete_capture)
```

Is there a recommended way to accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving the output of subprocess.call()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996518/retrieving-the-output-of-subprocess-call)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/616645/416224.

Comment: The other topics seem focused on simply capturing the output; whereas, I'm trying to both dump the output to stdout and capture it in its entirety for parsing on completion. I'm stuck at doing both simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track with using giving Popen `stdout=PIPE`, but you can't use `.communicate()` because it returns the values after execution. Instead, I suggest you read from [`.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdout).

The only guaranteed way to get the output the moment it's generated is to read from the pipe one character at a time. Here is my approach:

```py
def passthrough_and_capture_output(args):
    import sys
    import subprocess

    process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    # universal_newlines means that the output of the process will be interpreted as text
    capture = ""

    s = process.stdout.read(1)
    while len(s) > 0:
        sys.stdout.write(s)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        capture += s
        s = process.stdout.read(1)

    return capture
```

Note that reading one character at a time can incur significant overhead, so if you are alright with lagging behind a bit, I suggest that you replace the `1` in `read(1)` with a different number of characters to output in batches.

Answer (score -2):

```
from subprocess import check_output, CalledProcessError

def shell_command(args):
    try:
        res = check_output(args).decode()
    except CalledProcessError as e:
        res = e.output.decode()
    for r in ['\r', '\n\n']:
        res = res.replace(r, '')
    return res.strip()
```