# python code for retrieving output of subprocess (linux ps command)

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, output, ps

I would like to create python3 code to filter system processes by running the linux command 'ps'.

Here is my current code:

```
import subprocess,tempfile
command='ps -fe | grep java'
f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
run = subprocess.Popen([command],shell=True,stdout=f)
f.name

'/tmp/tmpswfw1_c8'
```

By running above code, we get a file containing the `ps` list, which has a 'java' entry in it. But when I `cat` the file, the long lines get cut. E.g. if the real process line is:

```
tomcat   21294     1 41 Jul06 ?        1-14:29:27 /opt/java/bin/java -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -jar /opt/microservices/apps-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.profiles.active=staging
```

this line is being processed into that `tempfile` by python as:

```
tomcat   21294     1 41 Jul06 ?        1-14:29:27 /opt/java/bin/java -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -jar /opt/microservices/apps[[other_chars_are_missing_here]]
```

The width in output file is same with the width in terminal when I run the python code.

How to correctly get the real output of `ps`?

### Edited by adding:

And I also get same truncated line with **subprocess.check_output**:

print (subprocess.check_output("ps -fe | grep java", shell=True))

Comment: this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996518/retrieving-the-output-of-subprocess-call/21000308

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite I think this is not a same question. I am able to get output, but some long lines in the output are being truncated.

Comment: then it could be a grep problem with environment variables, look in `os.environ' it might have something that tells grep to truncate itself

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is actually an issue with `ps`, not with Python. Try:

```
print(subprocess.check_output("ps -fe --width 1000 | grep java", shell=True))
```

or

```
print(subprocess.check_output("ps -wwfe | grep java", shell=True))
```

Comment: Thanks Oliver. It resolves the issue. But the command 'ps -fe | grep java' in bash/shell can output the correct lines in terminal or file, I can't understand how python truncate it when it gets these input from the upstream(ps or shell)?

Comment: Glad I could help. I've been frustrated by this issue before, and don't understand quite why it happens.