# Get output from curl command in python.

Tags: python, curl

How do I set the result of curl command to a variable, (So in this the ip address.)

```
import subprocess; ip = subprocess.call("curl ident.me", shell=True)
120.12.12.12

ip returns "0"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving the output of subprocess.call()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996518/retrieving-the-output-of-subprocess-call)

Comment: The .spilt() was what worked with "curl"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better to use `requests` module than running curl through shell

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://ident.me')
>>> r.text
'137.221.143.78'
>>>
```

If for some reason, you cant use `requests` module, then try using `subprocess.check_output`

```
>>> ip = subprocess.check_output("curl -s ident.me".split())
>>> ip
'137.221.143.78'
```