# return output from terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, operating-system

I would like to ask if is there a way to return to python a terminated value from terminal? For example I'm using `os.system` to write this line to ubuntu terminal

```
 cat /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp
```

to return a couple of values, and I would like to be able to access this values again in python code, is it possible?

Comment: you should check module [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and `psutil.sensors_temperatures()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have `*` in command so you have to use `shell=True` and shell will put full name in place of `*`

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.run('cat /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp', shell=True, capture_output=True)

print(process.stdout.decode())
```

Result on my Linux Mint:

```
66000
47000
```

Comment: thanks! This one worked. without shell it inputed "`*`" not as "all" but as just a "`x`"?

Answer (score 3):

`os.system` is being deprecated, or at least replaced by `subprocess`

You can capture output fairly easily with [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)

```
result = subprocess.run(['cat', '/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp'], capture_output=True)
print(result.stdout)
```

Comment: I tried it, but it says `unexpected keyword argument 'capture_output'` so I searched and find `stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE` insted of `capture_output`, but this one returns only `b' '`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an older version of Python(<3.5)

```
from subprocess import check_output
result = check_output(["cat", "/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp"])
print(result)
```

Comment: sorry I'm 3.6 :(

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for something like this: [Retrieving the output of subprocess.call()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996518/retrieving-the-output-of-subprocess-call)

example:

```
p = Popen(['ls', '-l'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate(b"input data that is passed to subprocess' stdin")
rc = p.returncode
```