# How to redirect PyInstaller output to wxPython textctrl

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, stdout, pyinstaller

I'm programming a GUI for pyinstaller. As part of the GUI, I would like to redirect the output of running `PyInstaller.__main__.run(['--onefile', 'foo.py'])` to a `wx.TextCtrl`.

I first went about this by writing a class `StdoutRedirector`:

```py
class StdoutRedirector(object):

    def __init__(self, outputwidget):
        self.out = outputwidget

    def write(self, text):
        self.out.WriteText(text)
```

Now this works fine for use with the `print` statement, but not with pyinstaller, which still prints to the terminal. Now I know pyinstaller uses the `logger` module for output, but I thought that went through `sys.stdout`.

Can anybody help me solve how to redirect this output to a textctrl widget?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996518/retrieving-the-output-of-subprocess-call

Comment: Yes and no - I want to call this from python code direct, and I've figured this out, but currently involves threads and lots more + will post code soon