# Python subprocess working in interactive mode but not in script

Tags: python, subprocess, sh

I'm trying to execute a shell script from python and also capture the output.

I'm using the following lines:

```
x = subprocess.run(["sh", "/path/to/script/myscript.bash"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(x.stdout.decode('utf8'))
```

This works fine when running in python interactive mode, but it just hangs when executed inside a python script and I have to use ctrl+Z to kill the python script. What am I missing?

In the past with python 2.7 I had just used a line like:

```
x = subprocess.Popen(args='sh /path/to/script/myscript.bash', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) 
scriptOutput = str(x.communicate()[0])
```

This doesn't seem to work with python 3.6 which is what I'm running.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving the output of subprocess.call()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996518/retrieving-the-output-of-subprocess-call)

Comment: Not really. My main issue right now isn't even capturing the output, it's the fact that the command won't execute when run from a python script.

Comment: what's the traceback.

Comment: How can I get a stack trace if the application is hanging and has to be killed?

Comment: add some debug to see where it's faulting, is this all the code in the script or is there more?

Comment: Insufficient information. What does *myscript.bash* do? Does it read from stdin? Also, why invoke `sh` explicitly? Your script should have a proper `#!` line (e.g., `#!/bin/sh`) in which case you can just execute it directly. When tackling a problem like this a useful strategy is to simplify the problem. For example, instead of executing your script try running `subprocss.run(['sh', '-c', 'echo hello'])`. If that works it means there is something about your script that is the problem. If it doesn't your python code is wrong.

Comment: @KurtisRader The shebang is only used if the script has execute permissions; neither is necessary to actually execute the script. `['sh', ...]` is fine (assuming the script is, in fact, written to the POSIX specification; otherwise, `['bash', ...]` should be used).

Comment: @chepner, I know that (I've been using UNIX for 35 years). It's simply more idiomatic and when I see 'sh /path/to/script' it's a red flag the person may not know what they're doing.