# Assigning a unique id to a GDB command script

Tags: gdb

I'd like to use a gdb command script to automatically run commands, and I need it to have a unique id.  This can be done manually via:

```
set $a = [unique id]
```

However, I'd like to do this programatically, somehting like:

set $a = shell myid.sh

where `myid.sh` prints a unique id.

However, I can't figure out how to load a gdb convenience var from the results of a shell command.

Comment: So I'm guessing the [shell exit code](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html#index-shell-command_002c-exit-code) isn't enough for you. In that case I would use python, e.g. like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47144897/1983398).

Comment: Do you just need an integer? `python import random; gdb.set_convenience_variable("a", str(random.randint(1,32000)))`