# Example of python script calling batch, then python script recieving batch script result?

Tags: python, batch-file

I am looking for an example of a python/batch script:

- python script calls up the command line
- python script passes a batch script (several lines) to the command line
- batch script then executes in the command line
- python script recieves the result of the batch script

I assume the solution would depend on some kind of special python library?

Would the task of combining python/batch be much easier if the processes starts in batch rather than in python (would this be a more common solution)?

Comment: Do you mean `bash` perhaps?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706989/how-to-call-an-external-program-in-python-and-retrieve-the-output-and-return-cod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code example:

```
import subprocess
bat_text = "dir" # (text to write in bat file)
bat_file = open("program.bat","w") # (open file in write mode)
bat_file.write(bat_text) # (write bat_text on bat_file)
bat_file.close() # (close file)
command = "C:\program.bat" # (the location of bat file)
execute = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)  # (exec the command)
output = execute.stdout.read() # (read output)
print output  # (print output)
```

subprocess tutorial

Comment: thanks! exactly what i was looking for.would vote up if i had over 15 reputation!

Answer (score 0):

See the subprocess module, which is included in the standard library:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

There are lots of examples there.