# How to display result in command prompt with python

Tags: python

Is it possible to display the result in command prompt if I run the python code is python GUI editor?

I mean, I have a program

```
def sum(a,b):
    result = a+b
    print "The sum = %d." %result

sum(2,3)
```

Once I run this code, I'm able to get the answer in the Python Shell window

```
The sum = 5.
```

What my question was, is it possible for me to get the result in windows command prompt instead of getting the result in Python Shell window.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706989/how-to-call-an-external-program-in-python-and-retrieve-the-output-and-return-cod

Comment: result of what? show your code and output that you expect

Comment: Not clear, what you are asking. Provide more explicit example of what you want to achieve (or what you are running and where you want to display the result).

Answer (score 0):

You can run python programs in Command Prompt by typing

```
Path/To/python.exe Path/To/python_script.py
```

which will output the answer

Comment: So I can't invoke the command prompt to display the result using python script?

Comment: Yes, I want to run the code in IDE but wants the result in windows command prompt. Is it possible?