# How to execute a python command in a python program

Tags: python, exec

I had made a text editor, and added a run command to it. So recently I am using exec() to execute commands but with big code it shows error. I want to make a run command like a build command in sublime text for my text editor. So how can I make a function to perform this program execution.

## It will be better if the function tell me the error too , like an any modern compiler does.

Comment: Check the accepted answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706989/how-to-call-an-external-program-in-python-and-retrieve-the-output-and-return-cod

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call an external program in python and retrieve the output and return code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706989/how-to-call-an-external-program-in-python-and-retrieve-the-output-and-return-cod)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the code inside a file and then call execute it with Popen.
This allows you to get the output of stdout and stderr.

Error output goes into stderr.
And normal output e.g. print goes into stdout

```
from subprocess import (
    Popen,
    PIPE,
)

python_cmd = Popen(('python3', 'test.py'), stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
output = python_cmd.communicate()
stdout = output[0].decode()
stderr = output[1].decode()
```

Comment: I am getting error that file not found default_compiler_location=open('defaultCompilerDist.py','w+')
default_compiler_location.write(str(txt.get("1.0", "end-1c")))
default_compiler_location.close()
default_compile_chr=py_compile.compile('defaultCompilerDist.py')
executedScript=Popen(['python3','defaultCompilerDist.py'],  stderr=PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
output = executedScript.communicate()
stdout = output[0].decode()
stderr = output[1].decode()
run_shell_text.insert(END,str(stdout))

Comment: The file ("defaultCompilerDist.py") is in the same folder of the main program.

Comment: As far as I can see it should find the file. You write the file. I dont know the purpose of using py_compile on it before using Popen. Also remove the .comunicate() after Popen because you are doing that already one line under it

Comment: i used py_compile.compile so that i can find any error in the code.

Comment: I cannot give input and cannot see time sleeps in my code. For example if I add time.sleep(3) in a code then by running it the whole output appears after 3 second. Can I get sleeps in my output.

Comment: how can I get the error line number or the line number which is showing error show that I can add a tag and highlight it?